# Differential equation; function in Octave

Tags: octave, differential-equations

I try to solve a differential equation in Octave. In a first attempt, all my independent variables are set constant (n,y,w). This is my code:

```
function xdot= f(x,t);

  % xdot=zeros(1,1);

  X=1.44221E+12;
  IO=5.318E+11;
  GO=6.81E+11;
  beta=0;
  gamma=0;
  y=58.5021088;
  w= 31.29;
  n=1363.5;
  tw=0.4;
  tp=0.3;
  sw=0.07;
  sp=0.25;
  mw=0.593941689;
  mp=0.593941689;

  % aw=(1-tw)(sw+mw)
  % ap=(1-tp)(sp+mp) 

  xdot=-(X+IO*(1+gamma*(diff(n)/n+diff(y)/y))+GO*beta(tw(diff(n)/n+diff(w)/w)+tp(diff(y)/y-diff(w)/w)-(x*n)/((y-w)((1-tp)(sp+mp)+tp)+((1-tw)(sw+mw)+tw)*w))*x)/(IO*gamma+GO*beta*tw);


 endfunction
```

When I add

```
 t = [0:(1/360):10]

 x = lsode ("f", 39290000, t);
```

to solve the equation in the command line, I get this error:

```
error: index (0.843942): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals
error: lsode: evaluation of user-supplied function failed
error: called from
f at line 23 column 7
```

It seems to me, in some way I misunderstood how to make the function.
Any help?

EDIT:

This is my new code:

```
function xdot= f(x,t);

 X=1.44221E+12;
 IO=5.318E+11;
 GO=6.81E+11;
 beta=0;
 gamma=0;
 y=58.5021088;
 w= 31.29;
 n=1363.5;
 tw=0.4;
 tp=0.3;
 sw=0.07;
 sp=0.25;
 mw=0.593941689;
 mp=0.593941689;

 xdot=-X+IO-(x*n)/((y-w)*((1-tp)*(sp+mp)+tp)+w*(tw+(1-tp)*(sp+mp)))

endfunction
```

It does work if I copy it into the command line but if I start it as programm (f.m) and solve it then I get this error:

```
error: 'x' undefined near line 25 column 15
error: called from
f at line 25 column 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of lsode](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Ordinary-Differential-Equations.html):

> Syntax: `[x, istate, msg] = lsode (fcn, x_0, t)`
> *...*
>
> The first argument, `fcn`, is a string, inline, or function handle that names the function f to call to compute the vector of right hand sides for the set of equations. The function must have the form
>
> ```
> xdot = f (x, t)
> ```
>
> in which xdot and x are vectors and t is a scalar.

So firstly, your `f` function is of the wrong form to the one expected by `lsode`, since it takes 5 arguments as opposed to 2.

Secondly, *inside* your `f` function, the variables `y`, `w`, and `n` are overwritten, regardless of whether they were supplied, whereas `t` and `x` need to be supplied by the user.

When `lsode` calls the handle `f`, it calls it with two arguments as per its specification, which means it instantiates `t` and `y`, and calls the function with the remaining input arguments undefined. Of the remaining arguments, `w` and `n` are given values inside the function, as we pointed out above, but `x` remains undefined. So when you run the final calculation which relies on `x`, you get an error saying it has not yet been defined during the call to this function.

So, to fix this issue, rewrite your function such that its signature is `f(x, t)`, which you can do so easily since `y`, `w`, and `n` are defined inside your function anyway, so they don't really need to be given as inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew that I was asking a dumb question, but I am still very confused. Obviously, to bring it in the right form xdot = f (x, t) is no big deal. Maybe I should ask the other way round:

Comment: I have a function x(t)= a*(x´/x)+b*(x´/x). I can obviously formulate  it as x(t)= or as x´(t)=., so here doesn't lay the problem. Additionally, I have these independent functions n,y and w. How do I get this into Octave? Because if i write xdot = f (x, t) here x is a vector and my variable is just a scalar!? Yes I know: Dumb question, but I don't get the point....

Comment: well, from what I can tell, lsode is specific to solving `dx/dt = f(x,t)` type equations, so you'll have to rearrange w.r.t. `dx/dt` first if you want to use this. As for n,y, and w being _functions_, you can define them as handles to anonymous functions, e.g. `n = @(z) z+5` returns a handle that you can run as `n(x)`. Read more on [function handles and anonymous functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Handles-Anonymous-Functions-Inline-Functions.html#Function-Handles-Anonymous-Functions-Inline-Functions) if you haven't come across this before.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I already had it in the form dx/dt= . I still get the same error after changing the function to xdot = f (x, t).

Comment: No, sorry, it is another error indeed, but as far as I can see, it doesn't recognize xdot. I edited the description new.

Comment: This is an entirely different error. The bug is where you do `diff(n)` etc. Since n here is a scalar, this produces an empty matrix, which cannot be used to index `tw` etc.

Comment: You're not supposed to run f by itself. Run the solver like you did before, i.e. `t = [0:(1/360):10]; x = lsode (@f, 39290000, t);`. This produces output for me. Having said that, I don't see where you're using t in that equation, but, meh. Btw, I'm answering because you're a new user, but please be aware that SO frowns on "extending" questions (this is a Q&A site, not a homework / techsupport site; you're supposed to ask a clear googlable question and select the answer that will also help others, not a series of extended queries to resolve a highly bespoke bug that's of no use to anyone else)